# localhost and root directory for multiple site installs

Tags: mamp, setup

So I usually have multiple sites inside of my MAMP htdocs folder which I then access through `localhost:8888/sitefolder`. How would this work for a Craft set up? The only way I got my initial Craft site to work was to point MAMPs document root to the public folder of the Craft site I was working on. But this seems pretty messy if I was to be working on multiple Craft sites at once. Surely I wouldn't need to keep changing my MAMP settings every time I wanted to look at another dev site?

Comment: I assume this is for MAMP and not MAMP Pro?  Have you seen things like https://una.im/2013/08/13/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-craft-on-mac/# and https://a73cram5ay.blogspot.com/2015/04/installing-craft-cms-on-mac-os-x-using.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use MAMP Pro to define seperate local url's for your projects? Or use something like Virtual Host X.

This way you can define some made up url like: yourporoject.dev and point that url to the public folder of your project.